# How to include css depends on the Running Enviroment

Tags: php, html, css

My Site Have Mobiles css and Desktop Css i have included that

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-width: 1320px)" href="styles/responsive-grid/small-desktop.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-width: 990px)" href="styles/responsive-grid/tablet.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-width: 660px)" href="styles/responsive-grid/mobile.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-width: 990px)" href="styles/tablet.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-width: 660px)" href="styles/mobile.css" />
```

this working fine but 
i need to include the desktop css only on Desktop, Mobile Css only on Mobile to Reduce the Requests

Comment: http://mobiledetect.net/

Answer (score 0):

Have a lok at something like [adapt.js](http://adapt.960.gs/) or write your own javascript.

Comment: i already tried this but it taking to much time for page  load